# editing products programmatically not affects in admin

Tags: product, admin

I added product programmatically and it was fine but when I tried to edit, it didn't appear in admin but when I print the product it appear with the new values.
I cant't figure why this happened.
is there is any one faced this problem before?

Comment: have you perform reindex?

Comment: yes I did this from the admin panel but not programmatically. do i need to do it programmatically after editing ?

Comment: is your complier is enable?

Comment: not it's disabled

Answer (score 1):

**Be sure you're viewing the correct store when trying to edit this product.**

Somewhere in the code you used to programmatically create this product, you should have the following lines of code:

```
$product->setWebsiteIDs(array($variable)); //probably 1
$product->save(); //make sure you remember to save the product
```

If the problem still persists, try the following in your source:

```
echo $product->getId();
```

Once you have the product ID, navigate to the `catalog_product_entity` table using something like PHPMyAdmin and see whether or not that ID exists in the table. Alternately you could run the following script:

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `entity_id` = ?';
$product = $connection->fetchRow($sql, $product_id); //your product id as the paramter
print_r($product);
die();
```

You should get something along the lines of the following output:

> Array ( [entity_id] => 13000 [entity_type_id] => 4 [attribute_set_id] => 4 [type_id] => simple [sku] => product_13000[created_at] => 2013-04-30 09:13:53 [updated_at] => 2013-07-09 19:28:59 [has_options] => 0 [required_options] => 0 )

That will indicate that you saved your product correctly.

Comment: I'm writing this line and it worked on adding products: Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
and i could print the product and it is saved in admin but when I edit it not appearing in admin but in printing I see it's new values
see this to know what i mean
https://scontent-b-cdg.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/10406727_10203051884291116_8712817957264915110_n.jpg

Comment: I also tried this query and got this result with updated today but still my problem nothing appear in admin
I also tried the same code in another magento project and it worked fine so the problem isn't in my code it could be some configuration I missed.